# Can we read a list as it was inverted in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, when we pass a list to a function we can read its elements one by one as in the following case:

```
check_acceptance :: Automaton -> Int -> [Char] -> Bool
check_acceptance a i (cs:c) = get_next_state c new_state (transitions a) where new_state = get_next_state cs i (transitions a)
```

Would it be possible to read it as it was inverted (but actually avoiding to invert it) by doing:

```
check_acceptance a i (c:cs) = ...
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: No, the pattern match matches a *cons* list object. Furthermore for infinite lists, that would be completely impossible anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using lists, no: reading from the end of a list efficiently requires reversing the list or something analogous. However, not all data structures are so picky. [Data.Sequence](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.11.0/docs/Data-Sequence.html#t:Seq) offers a type which, like lists, offers O(1) element insertion at the front (though this O(1) is amortized O(1), meaning any particular insertion can be arbitrarily expensive but averaging across many insertions gives very predictable performance), but unlike lists also offers (amortized) O(1) viewing and removal at the back.

Comment: You might want to add that `unsnoc` means "get the last element", that's not particularly obvious to a non-native speaker or someone who isn't familiar with the terminology (uncons is already bad enough, inverting the cons makes it quite difficult to parse).

Comment: @Cubic Good idea. I've edited to reduce the answer's reliance on jargon.